# How I can use array in exec and imgaemagick

Tags: php, arrays, imagemagick

I need to run a command line with imagemagick, php, exec().

I have an array like this:

```
$png[0];
$png[1];
$png[2];
$png[3];
$png[4];
...
```

then i have:

```
exec("convert ".$png['0']." ".$png['1']." ".$png['2']." -background none -gravity North -append result.jpg");
```

which work very good and create result.jpg by using -append, but i need use array like $png[] or in loop,because my $png[] key in array creates dynamic with a for loop on above of this codes.

any help please?
(sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your execution statement in variable before pass it to exec() function. It give you flexibility of using loop to add something in your statement.

```
$command = "convert ";
foreach($png as $value)
{
   $command .= $value." ";
}
$command .= "-background none -gravity North -append result.jpg";
exec($command);
```